# python Qt ibus error messages

Tags: python, qt

Running the following python program results in 2 error messages at startup.

```
ubuntu:~/Desktop/testing$ python test.py
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon
```

The errors occur in both Python and Python3.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        list = QtGui.QTableView(self)
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = MyApp()
myApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code runs fine for me (linux/cinnamon). Does this help? http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37362-no-connection-to-ibus-daemon-inotify_add_watch-failed

Comment: It got me to http://askubuntu.com/questions/360774/how-do-reactivate-ibus-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10 which suggested "ibus restart

ibus-setup" which did indeed get rid of the warnings.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/360774/how-do-reactivate-ibus-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10

```
ibus restart
ibus-setup
```

Running they python code after executing those commands makes the warnings go away.  The second command prompted me with "ibus daemon not running.  would you like to start it?".  The fact that it asked that explains why my python program could not connect.